# C#: Simplest way to dump a custom collection to csv file

Tags: c#, serialization, collections, csv

I have a class

```
public class DevicePatchInfo
{
  public string HostName { get; set; }
  public string PatchName { get; set; }
  public bool IsPresent { get; set; }   
}
```

I have a `List<DevicePatchInfo>` which is loaded with the data and is bound to a datagrid. I want to press a button and serialize this to a csv file.

The obvious way to do is to:

1. Create a StreamWriter with the csv path in the constructor.
2. Read all property names of the DevicePatchInfo class via reflection and write that as the first line in the csv file.
3. Enumerate over the List with a foreach.
4. Read each item in the list and create a string.format with comma separating all item values.
5. stream.write the new string
6. Dispose streamwriter when all done.

Huf ! Is there any simpler solution to this ? or I should've just typed the code instead of this.

Comment: Does it absolutely need to be CSV?  Are you simply trying to save the state?  If so, you might look into XML Serilaization: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813

Comment: @DavidStratton Yes, unfortunately it has to be a csv for reporting and excel importing purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the open-source [FileHelpers library](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/), which does this for you.

Comment: Darn you, @SLaks!  You always have a good answer!  It's hard to get any points with you around!  +1.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed solution is almost as close to the metal as you can get. I would suggest you hard-code the headers instead of using reflection, since the class you are writing, `DevicePatchInfo`, is well-defined.